TimeOut not happening even after adding CustomTimeoutInterceptor and calling withConnectTimeout
My whole intention is to add a timeout on a particular request.
For that I have added a CustomTimeoutInterceptor which has similar kind of code as stated below.
Even after setting timeout by calling chain.withConnectTimeout(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), the timeout is not taking affect.
I have already tried the placement of adding interceptor in the OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor().build() call
This is the code which is not working :
class CustomTimeoutInterceptor : Interceptor {
        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
             return chain.withConnectTimeout(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).proceed(chain.request())
        }
}

Also, can you please shed some light on using this block of code as solution?
How can it solve my problem? How can I use it correctly and safely? And how it works?
chain.call().timeout().timeout(timeout.value(), timeout.unit());
           RealCall realCall = (RealCall) chain.call();
           realCall.timeout.enter();

I am using
com.squareup.okhttp3 version 4.8.0
ApolloClient for graphql
Thanks in advance !!
I tried using
chain.call().timeout().timeout(timeout.value(), timeout.unit());
           RealCall realCall = (RealCall) chain.call();
           realCall.timeout.enter();

But I am not sure if it is ideal to use this, and what should be the correct way to use it
